# Unsafe member access on imports

Tags: typescript

I am getting unsafe member access on both `jose` and `queryString` from my eslint.

```
Unsafe member access .stringify on an `any` value.
Unsafe member access .JWK on an `any` value
```

These code run fine but ESLint is complaining about it. I am new to typescript and I would appreciate some help in solving these.

```
import jose from "node-jose";
import queryString from "query-string";

await jose.JWK.asKey
queryString.stringify(data)
```

Comment: both `node-jose` and `query-string` provide strong typing. You can see in this [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/werYgN) that `asKey` and `queryString` are not of type `any` so the eslint warning does not make sense to me.